# AFNetworking download from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I need to download one file from url when user press button.If user immediately press another button need to download that file after completion of first file.Immediately if press third button need to download that file also.How to achieve this with AFNetworking ?
Here my code sample to download file.Thanks in advance.

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/octet-stream",@"video/3gpp",@"audio/mp4",nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:[array objectAtIndex:0]   parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (responseObject) {

        NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:responseObject];

        NSLog(@"Download Succesfully Completed");

        //after completion I'm implementing my method here

        [self sentMsgSaveWithData:data orUrl:@"" withBool:YES withMsg_ID:@"" withDict:tempDict];


    } else {
        NSLog(@"Download Error");

    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Download Error %@",error.localizedDescription);


}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: you have to manage request for download when user press button .and in background you have download step by step

Comment: you can use synchronisation for it. Search for it synchronise donwload in ios

Comment: @ Himanshu Moradiya: How to handle request ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a session with default configuration:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

 NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: I want file data only.How to get file data ??

Comment: your file is downladed at the filePath from there u can do whatever u want with your file

Comment: But I want to download one by one on respective button press.So Do I need to go with NSOperationQueue ? After first button click if user clicks second one I should download both files but with respective button click order. Thank you.